# Group permissions there but cannot access file?

Tags: linux, file, permissions, edit, sftp

I sftp(ed) a simple text file from a windows machine to my home directory on my linux box and this was the file permissions it had ....

```
tom@bellmachine-6745:~$
----rwx--- 1 tom tom 6 Mar 16 12:45 redtest.txt
```

it said file belonged to group tom
it said file owned by tom
I was running terminal under tom

but touching redtest.txt gave me a "permission denied"
vi redtest.txt gave me a "permission denied" WHY ?

i could only edit when I was allowed to do the following on the file via .... 
chmod 670 redtest.txt

I owned the file
I was tom
And tom was a member of group tom
Ok there was only access to group tom members for this file so why had i to make those chmod changes it should have allowed me the very first time ???

Comment: Duplicate of [precedence-of-user-and-group-owner-in-file-permissions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134332/precedence-of-user-and-group-owner-in-file-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Because UNIX permissions work like this:  If you are the owner of the file, it looks at the owner permissions which are --- so there's permission denied.  If the file was owned by someone else, e.g. jane and jane would be in group tom, jane would be able to access it.  If the current user is not the owner of the file (tom) nor he is in the group tom the permissions for other would apply.

Note that root user (with UID 0) ignores permissions and he is able to access also file with no permissions set (---------- in ls output).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
sudo chmod r+w redtest.txt

Or do a chown:
chown tom redtest.txt

Answer (score 0):

The user permissions take precedence over group permissions. It's possible to own a file, but to have no permissions to it. You can change the permissions with

```
chmod u+rwx redtest.txt
```

If you want to change the default permission settings, use `umask`.